# Let the Django dev server run again after fixing the error in a . py file

Tags: django

> `AttributeError: module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'T'`

The Django server stopped working after showing this error message. After fixing the problem, how can I let the server to run again. It is now stuck.

I know that running `python manage.py runserver` is going to work. Is there a more convenient way?

Comment: You will need to share your forms.py file to help demonstrate context. The short answer is that you are trying to reference T from django.forms and that obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, Paschal, the error itself is irrelevant here. I fixed the error. However, the server is stuck. I needed to execute runserver again. It is annoying to do this every time after I fix something.

Comment: You can try using running the django server using `supervisor` service where it has support to restart the service automatically when it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors that runserver doesn't recover from. A lot it does recover from and as soon as a file is changed it will try again.

For the few that it can't: live with it - play some soothing music.

In PyCharm you can run the server within the IDE and restart it with one click when it's stuck. Otherwise, ctrl-c, arrow-up + enter is not going to wear out your keyboard or give you nerve damage.